# static ip xubuntu 13.04 not working at all (wlan0)

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, files, ip

Okay, so I am doing my file like this:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
iface wlan0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # I use the address I want 
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # 255.255.255.0
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # 192.168.2.1 my router ip
    DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      # 8.8.8.8 google
```

this just doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

It should be dns-nameservers, not DNS. Also, since this is a wireless interface, you must declare which network to connect to and supply the WPA password. I suggest:

```
auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
iface wlan0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # I use the address I want 
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # 255.255.255.0
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # 192.168.2.1 my router ip
dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      # 8.8.8.8 google
wpa-ssid your_router
wpa-psk your_secret_key
```

Now get the system to re-read the file and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0
```

Finally, may I assume Network Manager is not running here?